# ExtendedReport extension throws fatal error on WordPress Access Control save settings

Tags: wordpress

With the extension enabled (nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport) the settings in WordPress Access Control cannot be saved.

Disabling this extension allows the settings to be saved.

The error displayed is "API error: is not of type String". This is displayed when enabling the extension or saving WordPress Access Control settings.

This is on Wordpress 5.5.1, with CiviCRM 5.28.1.

This is the trace:

```
Exception: "API error: is not of type String"

#0 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(287): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->onApiError("ReportTemplate", "create", (Array:8), (Array:3))
#1 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(173): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->updateExistingEntity(Object(CRM_Core_DAO_Managed), (Array:4))
#2 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(146): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEnabledModule(Object(CRM_Core_Module), (Array:34))
#3 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(127): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEnabledModules()
#4 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(398): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcile()
#5 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/ACL/Form/WordPress/Permissions.php(179): CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches()
#6 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(504): CRM_ACL_Form_WordPress_Permissions->postProcess()
#7 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(144): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#8 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(45): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_ACL_Form_WordPress_Permissions), "next", "Next")
#9 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_ACL_Form_WordPress_Permissions), "next")
#10 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_ACL_Form_WordPress_Permissions), "next")
#11 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(347): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#12 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(98): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#13 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(285): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_ACL_Form_WordPress_Permissions", "WordPress Access Control", (Array:0))
#14 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#15 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#16 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1601): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#17 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#18 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#19 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#20 /Users/cfrost/vhosts/mysite.dev/httpdocs/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#21 {main}
```

Comment: This might get more attention if you opened an issue on https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport instead.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the extension fixed an issue with a report template, causing the error.